# Java Classpath help

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, executable-jar, jmf

I am using Java Media Framework and wrote a voice communication code. I included jmf.jar file for my voice chat to run. While using the eclipse IDE, i can run the code and it works. I now make the jar file by exporting the project into executable jar. When i run this jar using java -jar voice.jar, it doesn't work. I says cannot find devices. even-though i worked well in the IDE. I searched the net and found out that this may be a problem with the classpath. 
So how to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are using **Launch4j** Java launcher, you should put all your jars in **<cp>** XML elements. Make sure to organize all jars in one folder under the root application folder (the output folder for files generated by **Launch4j**). For example, if `voice.exe` is to be generated at `.\ ` folder, put all jars into `.\lib` folder and add Launch4j `<cp>lib\voice.jar</cp>` entry for `voice.jar`, one of the jars. If you don't like to have a special folder, just dump everything at the root but still correctly put **<cp>** entry for each jar.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your code is not detecting capture devices

you must copy the jmf.properties file to the same directory as your executable jar

you will find the jmf.properties file int the lib folder of your jmf installation.

For me it was C:\Program Files\JMF2.1.1e\lib\jmf.properties

Answer (score 0):

Try

`java -classpath <locationofjar>/voice.jar;<locationofjar>/jmf.jar Program`

Comment: Yep! That and bear the the classpath in windows uses ; as in linux uses :

Comment: For this command, java.exe should be executed from where your .class file is located